# Distribution Cleanup failure

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

The [Distribution Cleanup: Distribution] job, which removes replicated transactions from the distribution database, failed due to an error when executing the sp_MSdelete_publisherdb_trans procedure. I found that the error is related to accessing rows in the [dbo].[MSrepl_commands] table for a specific publisher_database_id,
In other words, the query:

```
select Count(*)
from dbo.MSrepl_commands with (nolock) 
where publisher_database_id = 28
```

failed with the message "An inconsistency was detected during an internal operation. Please contact technical support."
On the other hand, running these queries:

```
DBCC CHECKDB('distribution')
-- CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'distribution'.

DBCC CHECKTABLE ('dbo.MSrepl_commands')
--DBCC results for 'MSrepl_commands'.
--There are 7624545 rows in 527310 pages for object "MSrepl_commands".
--DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

doesn't reveal any logical or physical integrity errors. I thought DBCC CHECKDB and DBCC CHECKTABLE are applicable to the [distribution] database,
and in particular DBCC CHECKTABLE is applicable to the [dbo].[MSrepl_commands] table. If we assume that there are no integrity issues with the table, then what could be other possible reasons for the error on accessing the data of this table?

The instance has the following version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU2) (KB4482960) - 12.0.6214.1 (X64)

Comment: Could be a storage problem.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Thanks for the response. In my case, restarting the SQL Server service fixed the problem, but anyway I'm going to check the storage as a precaution.